# How do we make nginx work for subdir applications?

Tags: nginx, php

I need to have some applications organized by subdir, here are the urls I will use for them:

```
http://172.17.0.158/beanstalk
http://172.17.0.158/phpmyadmin
http://172.17.0.158/laravel
```

I need it to be IP or any hostname, so I set my server_name as:

```
server_name  "";
```

I need it to be "folder like" applications, but those applications are installed in different roots.

Two of them are working fine:

```
http://172.17.0.158/beanstalk
http://172.17.0.158/phpmyadmin
```

And one, I cannot make work:

```
http://172.17.0.158/laravel
```

Here is my server block for those:

```
server {

    listen       172.17.0.158:80;

    # Anonymous server (ip or hostname)
    server_name  "";   ## this is an IP address (or wrong server_name) based server

    # Configure log
    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log debug;

    # Index files
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # PHP scripts are sent to php5-fpm
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME
                                  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include                   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {

        deny all;

    }

    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|svg|woff|webp)$ {

        expires max;

    }

    include /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Here are my location (`/etc/nginx/locations-enabled/`) files:

File /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/beanstalkd-console.conf **(this one is working fine)**

```
location /beanstalk {

    root /var/www/beanstalk_console;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/beanstalkd-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/beanstalkd-error.log debug;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/beanstalk/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index             index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/beanstalk/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /var/www/beanstalk_console;
    }

}

location /beanstalkd {
    rewrite ^/* /beanstalk last;
}

location /beanstalk_console {
    rewrite ^/* /beanstalk last;
}
```

Beanstalk file is working, but, to do so, I had to create a **silly** symbolic link: /var/www/beanstalk_console/beanstalk points to /var/www/beanstalk_console/public. I could not make root nor alias to work. After hours trying and guessing what Nginx wanted I gave up and created the link.

File /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf **(this one is working fine)**

```
location /phpmyadmin {

    root /usr/share/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index             index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
    }

}

location /phpMyAdmin {
       rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```

This one pleases Nginx, because phpmyadmin is a folder inside /usr/share. So no tweaks to make it work.

File /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/laravel.conf **(NOT WORKING)**

```
location /laravel {

    alias /var/www/laravel/public;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log debug;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/laravel/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /var/www/laravel/public;

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index             index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/laravel/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        alias /var/www/laravel/public;
    }

}
```

For the sake of me I could not make this one work. When I try to access, it produces this debug messages:

```
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 8
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 9
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 10
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 try files phase: 12
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 content phase: 13
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 content phase: 14
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 open index "/var/www/laravel/public/index.php"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 internal redirect: "/laravel/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 8
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 9
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 access phase: 10
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 try files phase: 12
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http script copy: "/var/www/laravel/public"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http script var: "/laravel/index.php"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 trying to use file: "/laravel/index.php" "/var/www/laravel/public/laravel/index.php"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 trying to use file: "=404" "/var/www/laravel/public=404"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/laravel/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http special response: 404, "/laravel/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http set discard body
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 xslt filter header
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2013 21:45:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip

2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000000000156F898, pos 000000000156F898, size: 194 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:194
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http output filter "/laravel/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http copy filter: "/laravel/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 image filter
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 xslt filter body
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http postpone filter "/laravel/index.php?" 000000000156FAC8
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http gzip filter
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 malloc: 0000000001564D50:16384
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:1 s:5936 a:8192 p:0000000001564D50
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:1024 s:2 a:2048 p:0000000001566D50
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:1024 s:2 a:2048 p:0000000001567550
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:1024 s:2 a:2048 p:0000000001567D50
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:512 s:4 a:2048 p:0000000001568550
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000156FB08
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156F970 ni:00000000006BE7C0 ai:116
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 posix_memalign: 0000000001568D60:4096 @16
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 malloc: 00000000015AF180:4096
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate in: ni:00000000006BE7C0 no:00000000015AF180 ai:116 ao:4096 fl:0 redo:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate out: ni:00000000006BE834 no:00000000015AF180 ai:0 ao:4096 rc:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156F970 pos:00000000006BE7C0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000156FB18
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156F9C0 ni:00000000006BE120 ai:61
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate in: ni:00000000006BE120 no:00000000015AF180 ai:61 ao:4096 fl:0 redo:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate out: ni:00000000006BE15D no:00000000015AF180 ai:0 ao:4096 rc:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156F9C0 pos:00000000006BE120
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000156FB28
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156FA10 ni:00000000006BE1A0 ai:402
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate in: ni:00000000006BE1A0 no:00000000015AF180 ai:402 ao:4096 fl:4 redo:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 deflate out: ni:00000000006BE332 no:00000000015AF234 ai:0 ao:3916 rc:1
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000156FA10 pos:00000000006BE1A0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 0000000001564D50
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http chunk: 10
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http chunk: 188
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000000000156F898, pos 000000000156F898, size: 194 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000000001568ED0, pos 0000000001568ED0, size: 4 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006C25C8, size: 10 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 00000000015AF180, pos 00000000015AF180, size: 188 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000000000049DAD8, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:1 s:403
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http write filter limit 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 writev: 403
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/laravel/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/laravel/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/laravel/index.php?" a:1, c:1
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 set http keepalive handler
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http close request
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http log handler
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 00000000015AF180
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 000000000156EB40, unused: 8
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 0000000001568D60, unused: 3315
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 event timer add: 3: 65000:1382305592455
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 000000000156E210
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 000000000156E730
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 tcp_nodelay
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 post event 00007F0777F20148

==> /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log <==
172.17.0.100 - - [20/Oct/2013:19:45:27 -0200] "GET /laravel/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"

==> /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log <==
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 delete posted event 00007F0777F20148
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 malloc: 000000000156E210:1024
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 recv: fd:3 -1 of 1024
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2013/10/20 19:45:27 [debug] 27308#0: *1 free: 000000000156E210
```

What I could not understand is why it does get a right index.php file:

```
open index "/var/www/laravel/public/index.php"
```

And then gives me a

```
*1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This is the last version of it. This is another one:

```
location ~ ^{{ laravel_site_base_url }}(/?(.*))$ {

    root {{ webserver_document_root }}{{ laravel_site_base_url }}/public;

    # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
    try_files   $uri /index.php?$2 /index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx{{ laravel_site_base_url }}-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx{{ laravel_site_base_url }}-error.log debug;

    location ~ ^{{ laravel_site_base_url }}/(.+\.php)$ {
        root {{ webserver_document_root }}{{ laravel_site_base_url }}/public;

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index             index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                   {{ nginx_config_directory }}/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;            
    }

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

This one produces this debug log:

```
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 http script regex: "^/(.*)/$"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [notice] 27842#0: *1 "^/(.*)/$" does not match "/laravel", client: 172.17.0.100, server: , request: "GET /laravel HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.0.158"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 access phase: 8
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 access phase: 9
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 access phase: 10
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 try files phase: 12
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 http script var: "/laravel"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 trying to use file: "/laravel" "/var/www/laravel/public/laravel"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 http script copy: "/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 http script capture: ""
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 trying to use file: "/index.php?" "/var/www/laravel/public/index.php?"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 trying to use file: "/index.php" "/var/www/laravel/public/index.php"
2013/10/20 19:49:12 [debug] 27842#0: *1 internal redirect: "/index.php?"
```

And in the browser I see

```
No input file specified.
```

People in the #nginx were telling this is a PHP problem, I don't buy it, because it was based on this server block, that was working really fine before I started to change things:

File: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel **(was working before having to make changes)**

```
server {

    listen       172.17.0.158:80;

    server_name  "";   ## this is an IP address (or wrong server_name) based server

    location ~ ^/laravel(/?(.*))$ {

        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files   $uri /index.php?$2;

        root /var/www/laravel/public/;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log error;

    }

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass              unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index             index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info   ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param             SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|svg|woff|webp)$ {

        expires max;

    }        

}
```

Anyone has anything to say about all this?

Comment: "No input file specified." Is a problem between nginx and php. I would guess that nginx sends a path to php that php can't open. You should look into the php (php-fpm?) error logs to see what is happening.

Comment: Nothing shows up on `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`. Log level raised to debug `log_level = debug` and set `error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm-error.log`, this error log file is not even created, so I'll assume that there were nor errors. This is what shows on the log: `[21-Oct-2013 12:04:30] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful`.